Power BI deployment details are reflecting in Audit portal
I'm a power bi administrator and need help regarding audit from Compliance portal.
We are required to do quarterly audit on the changes happened in a workspace for the current quarter.
power bi deployment for that workspace is done using a deployment pipeline.But this information is not available in the audit portal if we gave the workspace name as a keyword .
for example i have a workspace named "Hallo". i use "x" deployment pipeline to update the reports in "Hallo".when i extract audit from microsoft compliance portal with a keyword "Hallo" i am not getting any records ,if i remove the keyword i can see the deployment details but that records does not contain any detail related to the "Hallo" workspace. How can i prove this deployment details are related to "Hallo" workspace?
I tried to find any details are matching to the workspace ,But none of them confirm it is related to the workspace

Can you check if auditing is enabled?
